# Hidden multi select in angular

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I'm trying to build a custom multi select form input () so that I can send an array of items through a form. The format of the data needs to be native to rails, like:

```
item[tags][]=1,5,7
```

Normally I would do this by coding:

```
<select multiple="multiple" name="item[tags][]">
   <option value="1">A</option>
   <option value="2">B</option>
   <option value="3">C</option>
</select>
```

But as I mentioned earlier, this information needs to be hidden because I am customizing the look of the control. Any ideas how I could pass data in this way using angular?

(please let me know if my explanation is clear enough)

Comment: what about putting one ng model?

Comment: ive gotten this far: <input type="hidden" name="drug[drug_class_ids][]" value="{{selected_drug_classes}}"/> The only problem is that selected_drug_classes is an array of hashes like {id:1, name:"My Class"}. I need to get just the ids

Comment: really not clear what problem is...you have full control over data in your custom plugin/directive  `ng-model="formDatObject.tags` should work...pass array to to it then `join` array when sending `$http`

Comment: the only thing I'm missing is doing something like ng-model="formDatObject.tags.id"

Comment: Updated question at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20011198/passing-an-array-in-a-hidden-input