# Passing an array in a hidden input

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm attempting to pass an array of values in a hidden input using angular. Here is my code so far:

```
<input type="hidden" name="drug[drug_class_ids][]" value="{{selectedDrugClassIds()}}"/>
```

where

```
$scope.selectedDrugClassIds = function ()
{
    var selected_drug_class_ids = [];
    for (var x in $scope.selected_drug_classes)
    {
        selected_drug_class = $scope.selected_drug_classes[x];
        console.log(selected_drug_class);
        selected_drug_class_ids.push(selected_drug_class.id);
    }

    return selected_drug_class_ids;
};
```

But this is giving me the incorrect

```
"drug_class_ids"=>["[15,5,8]"]
```

Where I need

```
"drug_class_ids"=>["15", "5", "8"]
```

Any ideas how I could fix this?

Comment: Are you using PHP for your server?  If you are, `json_decode` would work.

Answer (score 1):

Got it!

This was an interesting one:

```
    <div ng-repeat="drug_class in selected_drug_classes">
      <input type="hidden" name="drug[drug_class_ids][]" value="{{drug_class.id}}"/>
    </div>
```

Comment: Since it is all hidden, what was the purpose here ? having the fields added to the validation object ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because angular stores the array as a string in the hidden field instead of the actual array. So just stringify it to json in angular and decode it in back end.